# Why is this array_search returning 0

Tags: php, arrays

Consider the following:

```
$characterStats = [
            ['strength' => 500],
            ['dexterity' => 200],
            ['agility' => 1000],
            ['intelligence' => 1200],
            ['health' => 675],
        ];

$stat = array_search(max($characterStats), $characterStats);

echo $stat;
```

- **What I expect:** `['intelligence' => 1200]`
- **What I get:** 0

Can some one help me out to achieve what I want?

Comment: Are you sure you need this as a multidimensional array (which is causing the problem BTW)?

Comment: You might want to check http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php because your arrays are "uncomparable" in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
 $characterStats = array(
            'strength' => 500,
            'dexterity' => 200,
            'agility' => 1000,
            'intelligence' => 1200,
            'health' => 675,
        );

$stat = array_search(max($characterStats), $characterStats);

echo $stat;
```

I changed the way the array is declared. I believe you may need to indicate the field name you would like to search if using nested arrays with the following call:

```
$stat = array_search(max($characterStats), array_column($characterStats, 'KEYNAME'));
```

However, since each sub array has only 1 element with different "key" it may not be the best approach. For your scenario, you may need to use another approach, where you loop through each element and store the max value found.

Comment: Expected output is ['intelligence' => 1200] , this only returns intelligence

Comment: I edited to indicate that this was not the intended use of array_search, and another search should be used for nested arrays

Answer (score 1):

With the array as you have it at the moment, the easiest way I can think of doing it as a standard `foreach()` and keep the maximum value as well as the element where it's found (save doing another search to get the full entry)...

```
$characterStats = [
    ['strength' => 500],
    ['dexterity' => 200],
    ['agility' => 1000],
    ['intelligence' => 1200],
    ['health' => 675],
];

$maxStat = null;
$max = null;
foreach ( $characterStats as $stat ){
    if ( current($stat) > $max )    {
        $max = current($stat);
        $maxStat = $stat;
    }
}
print_r( $maxStat);
```